# SQL syntax error. However, it works normally at phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I have this error :

```
[You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4]

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_postmeta AS a, wp_postmeta AS b 
WHERE a.post_id = b.post_id AND (a.meta_key = 'customer_email' 
AND a.meta_value LIKE '%sample@ex.com%') AND (b.meta_key = 'usage_count' AND b.meta_value = '0'
```

However, it works normally at PHPMYADMIN

I don't know what went wrong.

my code is

```
$rowcount = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM $wpdb->postmeta AS a, $wpdb->postmeta AS b WHERE a.post_id = b.post_id AND (a.meta_key = 'customer_email' 
AND a.meta_value LIKE '%sample@ex.com%') AND (b.meta_key = 'usage_count' AND b.meta_value = '0'");

echo $rowcount;
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

) bracket missing in last condition. (i.e AND (b.meta_key = 'usage_count' AND b.meta_value = '0'"); )

```
 $rowcount = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM $wpdb->postmeta AS a, $wpdb->postmeta AS b WHERE a.post_id = b.post_id AND (a.meta_key = 'customer_email' 
AND a.meta_value LIKE '%sample@ex.com%') AND (b.meta_key = 'usage_count' AND b.meta_value = '0')");

echo $rowcount;
```

Comment: I made a really stupid mistake.
Thank you for saving my time.